# Opening a file without knowing the name

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file

In my application I am using a timestamp as my filename when I save it to a folder on my device.I know want to access one of these files from my application but I'm not sure how to open a file that you don't know the name of. They are all of the same file type so my question is how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to save to a particular directory that only contains your timestamped files and nothing else. You can use the File.listFiles API to get an array of Files in your directory, you can then check each of the filenames to find the appropriate one (e.g. most recent timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the name of file.Otherwise it would be like saying to JVM "do this?" without the idea of what to do?